# Grouping Account Kanban List View by Owner

Tags: account, list-view, kanban

One of my Users created a Kanban List View for Accounts which grouped them by Owner.  The original problem was that there were several (deprecated) Record Types that were splitting the records up.  I went in and cleaned up the record types so that they were correct. The unintended consequence of this was that the Kanban settings were now grouped by a different Picklist field and I cannot select Owner in the Group by settings.

I originally thought you could only group by a Picklist field so I was surprised she was able to group by Owner, however according to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=kanban_configuration.htm&type=5 it says

> To determine how your records are organized into columns, select a
>   picklist such as Stage to group by, **or group records by owner**.

As I said before, when I get into the Kanban settings, there is no option to group by Owner.  I also did not see an option to group by Owner before the Record Type cleanup.

A search for how to group by owner did not return any useful insights and I know of no other way to alter Kanban group settings. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [Kanban Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=kanban_considerations.htm&type=5) it mentions as below:

> Records are only displayed if the fields selected for **Group By** and **Summarize By** are in a page layout assigned to a record type that the user has access to.

You should verify if after restructuring the record types, if you have the `Account Owner` field available in the page layout for that record type. If not, adding the field in the page layout will let you Group By the Owners.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.  This slipped by me as I was not aware of any changes to any of my Page Layouts but it looks like a change was made by one of our third party consultants which did not make it into their discussions with me so I did not think to check here but that was it. I had a new Page Layout that did not have Account Owner on it.  Thank you.